# Why are register values not changing while debugging?

Tags: debugging, assembly, compiler-construction

I'm new to assembly and there is a question that really bothers me. While debugging, one can see the values of registers. You can pause the execution, observe, etc. My question is how is this possible. Registers are general purpose so every program that is running would be able to access and change them. 
Some kind of lock on registers seems ineffective because it would make other program error prone. 
So how does this work. More insightful answers and explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is very simple answer. The debugger (and/or OS dependent debug API) saves the values of the registers in the memory, then takes the control and displays the debugger screen.

Later, when you want to continue the execution of the debugged program, the debugger restores the values and continues the execution.

This happens on every instruction executed, if you want to execute the instructions one by one.

Answer (score 1):

What johnfound said.

assembly has the ability to move register values to memory (for x86/x64 architecture anyway) onto a stack. In intel x86 you can move all the general purpose registers onto the stack with one instruction.

When you get to writing functions in assembly, you will start saving the state of registers you use in the function yourself, and restoring them at the end of the function.